# What is the function of "have" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

She could **have** passed the test if she had studied harder.

In this sentence could is modal verb.

then what is **have**.
main verb,or helping verb?

Comment: "Have" is the **perfect auxiliary** verb.

Comment: Note that auxiliary verbs are also known as helping verbs. Could is also a helping verb but another type called modal auxiliary verb.

Comment: @SyedDanishAnwar No substance can be given to the idea that auxiliaries are “helping verbs”. I would thus strongly recommend dropping the term.

Comment: @BillJ, your latter comment contradicts your former.  You're claiming that the very substance you've given can't be given.

Comment: @BillJ In the ESL teaching world, the terms "auxiliary verb" and "helping/helper verb" are used interchangeably. Some textbooks stick to the latter because it's easier to understand. I get why you don't like the term, but it's meaningful to a lot of ESL students who may never have heard the term "auxiliary verb".

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers have not explained is that using these past constructions makes it a *irrealis* or *counter-factual* conditional.

> She could pass the test if she tries

is not counter-factual: it hasn't happened yet and it might.

> She could have passed the test if she tried

is counter-factual: it implies that she didn't pass the test, and the conditional is hypothetical.

Comment: I agree - but I would feel bound to backshift the subsequent verb "...if she had tried", or "...had she tried".  Equally "She could pass the test if she tried". Am I just unfashionable?

Comment: I would probably say _if she had tried_ (or, more likely, _if she'd tried_, so the _'d_ would be inaudible in rapid speech) myself; but I would not object to the form without _had_.

Comment: Of course, what we all say in casual speech, can be quite different to that which we'd write in an essay. And many a disagreement on these sites is occasioned by people simply coming at the same thing from different positions.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates the perfect past tense, as an auxiliary verb. The present-tense version is:

> She could pass the test if she tried

The past tense is then:

> She could have passed the test if she had tried